# How to use socket.io with a remote server?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying implementing socket.io but in the tutorials that I follow it says to connect server.js to a local index.html file:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.end(content);
});
```

});

Since, my site files are on another server, how can I just connect to the remote server that has socket.io. And how to instance my server.js without loading an index.html file?

(I just want the basics of web sockets: send and receive message)

Comment: In your index.html that is served from SERVER1 you need to reference a socket.io script from SERVER2 <script src="http://[SERVER2 IP]:[PORT]/socket.io/socket.io.js"> and then you can connect to it var socket = io.connect("http://[SERVER2 IP]:[PORT]");

Comment: Thanks, And I just create an index.html file with nothing in it (on server 2)?

Comment: No you don't need any html on server2